# What is a word for the receiver of a notification?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't believe "notified" is accurate, as it implies the notification has been already made and received.

I'm looking for a word that labels a recipient that specifically is waiting for a notification.  The word "recipient" is technically viable, but then one asks "what are you receiving?  A gift?  A punishment?  An inheritance?".

Does a word exist that encapsulates being a recipient of,  specifically, notifications?

Comment: The person to whom any utterance is addressed is called its ***Addressee***. This applies to notifications, questions, orders, etc; any kind of speech act has a speaker and an addressee. With verbs of speech or communication these are usually encoded as subject and object of some kind _She informed me of the issue; She told me the issue; She asked me about the issue_.

Comment: @deadrat yep, a duplicate, thanks :D should I just  delete or wait for the votes to come in?

Comment: I'd leave it. Those interested will have a pointer for a while.

Comment: Is this for software engineering?  If so, it's referred to as the observer pattern

Comment: @publicwireless partially, but "observer pattern" is not intuitive; the observer is *called* when the observ**ed** changes, meaning the active member of the relationship is the *observed*.  The word "observer" implies the one that is called is the active one, which isn't the case.